# Question about PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

When the game starts in multiplayer, the master client sends a PunRPC to have all clients run a function. This function tries to get the room properties to see if the game is active, if so it does something. For some reason a client gets a null reference error, but the master client does not. The strange thing is, a debug of the hash table for room properties is visible but I cannot get a specific item in it.

Tried Debugging the hash table to make sure that the key was set when the code was run. It was. "(System.String)ag=(System.Boolean)True ag=activeGame" This shows in `Debug.Log(hash);` But `(bool)hash[rpk.activeGame]` gets a null reference error. But only on the client side not the master client. So the key also works.

```cs
// Call all the clients to set up the room settings in the sub menu.
    [PunRPC]
    private void GameRoomSetup (string pOne, string pTwo, int pOneColor, int pTwoColor)
    {
        GameObject gameMenu = GameObject.Find ("GameMenu");

        gameMenu.GetComponent<SubMenu> ().UpdatePlayers (pOne, pTwo, pOneColor, pTwoColor);
        gameMenu.GetComponent<SubMenu> ().StartGameSetup ();

        // If you are a player, change the active buttons that are visible.
        if (PhotonNetwork.NickName == pOne || PhotonNetwork.NickName == pTwo) 
        {
            gameMenu.GetComponent<GameButtonManager> ().GameStart ();
        }

        hash = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
        Debug.Log(hash);
        if ((bool)hash[rpk.activeGame]) // Error on this line on client but not on master client. Says null reference.
        {
            GameObject.Find ("SoundManager").GetComponent<SoundManagerScript> ().PlayBackgroundTwo ();
            GameObject.Find ("GameMenu").GetComponent<SubMenu> ().ChangeSubMenuActive (false);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to run my if statement as a client but I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

To get a custom property, I recommend you use `TryGetValue` method as follows:

```
    hash = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
    object temp;
    string key = rpk.activeGame;
    if (hash.TryGetValue(key, out temp))
    {
        if (temp is bool)
        {
            bool activeGame = (bool)temp;
        }
        else
        {
            // unexpected custom property value type
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // custom property not found
    }
```

If the custom property is not available yet, wait for the callback `IInRoomCallbacks.OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(Hashtable propertiesThatChanged)` ([reference API](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/interface_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_i_in_room_callbacks.html#ace378cf7df21ab802b2a0d144264e6c5)).

Other notes and recommendations:

```
private void GameRoomSetup (string pOne, string pTwo, int pOneColor, int pTwoColor)
```

Not sure if it's supported or if it's a good idea to pass multiple parameters to a PUN RPC method.

To debug log a `Dictionary` or a `Hashtable` you could make use of `SupportClass.DictionaryToString()` method.
so instead of

```
Debug.Log(hash);
```

use

```
Debug.Log(SupportClass.DictionaryToString(hash));
```

Avoid calling expensive methods like `GameObject.Find`:

```
    GameObject gameMenu = GameObject.Find ("GameMenu");
```

Also here you have duplicate calls to `gameMenu.GetComponent<SubMenu>()`, at least call it once and cache the component result found if any.

```
    gameMenu.GetComponent<SubMenu> ().UpdatePlayers (pOne, pTwo, pOneColor, pTwoColor);
    gameMenu.GetComponent<SubMenu> ().StartGameSetup ();
```

Comparing strings should not be done using `==` operator. At least use Equal method and proper StringComparison type. Read "[How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)".

```
    // If you are a player, change the active buttons that are visible.
    if (PhotonNetwork.NickName == pOne || PhotonNetwork.NickName == pTwo) 
    {
        gameMenu.GetComponent<GameButtonManager> ().GameStart ();
    }
```

Besides, why do you use the Nickname to check if it's player one or two? maybe use ActorNumber or a custom player index. Or use the player count if the room is for 2 players only.